# I got error when try to use ctypes module in Python

Tags: python, c, dll, module, ctypes

I started learn ctypes module and i got this error when try to run my code: `cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")`

```
NameError: name 'cdll' is not defined
```

My code:

```
from ctypes import *

print(windll.kernel32)
print(cdll.msvcrt)

cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
print(libc)

libc.printf

print(windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA)
getattr(cdll.msvcrt, "??2@YAPAXI@Z")

print(libc.time(None))
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: do you run `Linux`? `cdll` probably exists only on `Linux`. I run code on `Linux` and I don't have `windll` because it exists only on `Windows`. You should use some `if/else` (probably with `sys.platform`) to run different code for different systems

Comment: Hi, renaming the file fixed the problem. Thanks for your help.